# Styling input type range elements in Webkit browsers

Tags: css, html, webkit

Is there any way to style `<input type="range">` elements for Webkit browsers?

Comment: input type `button, checkbox, file, hidden, image, password, radio, reset, submit, text` **new input type** `reset, image, datetime, datetime-local, date, month, time,week, number, range, email, url, search, tel, color` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/

Comment: ohhh Sorry its input type range only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only heard of the type `range`, not `slider`.

```
input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-horizontal;
}
```

Comment: how to change the color and appearance , is their any way to change the appearance of knob too.

Answer (score 14):

There is a pretty good article on [styling a range to make it look like an iPhone slider](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/implementing-iphone-slider-unlock-with-input-type-range) written by David B. Calhoun.

I think the blog post should cover most aspects of styling a range input type.

Here is some of the CSS:

```
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 68px;
    height: 44px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #fefefe),
        color-stop(0.49, #dddddd),
        color-stop(0.51, #d1d1d1),
        color-stop(1, #a1a1a1)
    );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
}
```